# Send email on html button click

Tags: javascript, php, html, email

I want to send an email as soon as I click on html button. To do this task, I've written following code

**HTML code:**

```
<button onclick="sendEmail()">Send Email</button>
<p id="mailStatus"></p>
```

**Java Script Code:**

```
function sendEmail()
{
     $.ajax({
           url: "mail.php",
           type: "POST",
           success: function(response) {
               if (!response) {
                    alert("Something went wrong. Please try again");
                    return;
               }

               var parsedJSON = eval('('+response+')');

               // If there's an error, display it.
               if(parsedJSON.Error) {
                  // Handle session timeout.
                  if (parsedJSON.Error == "Timeout") {
                       alert("Session timed out. Please login again.");
                       window.location.reload();
                   }
                }
               document.getElementById('mailStatus').innerHTML = "Email Sent successfully";  
            }
     });
}
```

The problem if when I click on Send Email button, I get an error message as

`"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"`

Can someone please help??

Comment: have you added jquery?

Comment: no.. as I am new to this thing, where should I add jquery???

Comment: *var parsedJSON = eval('('+response+')');* why eval?

Comment: @RaviSingh You have to add the Jquery library in your script files. 
Below is the link for Jquery reference https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.js

Comment: Thanks @Steve and Divyesh. Vicky, I copied the JS code, didn't realise about eval. I'll fix it up now.. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `$.ajax` is function of jQuery so you need to add jQuery in your file.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Add this line above `sendMail` function.

Comment: Awesome.. thanks mate.. This resolved my issue.